# WIll Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS work on my Dell Vostro 14-3468 Machine?

Tags: dell-vostro

I want to install Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. But the minimum Processor required is 2GHz while my processor shows
Processor : Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU 3865U @ 1.80GHz, 1800 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 2 Logical Processor(s)

I want to know if I can install Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS and if not any other alternatives?

Edit: Seeing my Processor Specification can I say It is 1.80 GHz which is less than what is required (2 GHz)

Comment: If you boot a live installation medium (DVD, USB), you will immediately see if that succeeds, so whether Ubuntu can run on your system.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/q/206407/)

Comment: I've QA-tested Ubuntu releases up to current *jammy* (what will be 22.04 on release in a couple of months) on machines as old as from 2005 (ie. c2d boxes) and I really don't consider the speed of the CPU that much.  The RAM in my opinion matters more; and what you'll run on it (ie. will desktop match the apps you'll use; what will you have co-existing in RAM at the same time etc..).  If your machine is lacking resources (as boxes from 2005 usually are), lighter desktops usually give a much better performance (eg. Lubuntu for Qt5 apps, or Xubuntu for GTK3 apps etc).

Comment: If you want to use an official Ubuntu flavor, you can try [Xubuntu](https://xubuntu.org/), [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.me/). If you need a more lightweight operating system, try [MX Linux](https://mxlinux.org/) and [antiX](https://antixlinux.com/antix-21-grup-yorum-released/). Note that the last two are not supported on this site, but you can ask questions about them on http://unix.stackexchange.com/